# JS app not running over https on aws

Tags: javascript, https

I have a JS app running on aws ec2 - the original calls to the app were http - but when changed to https the call is refused - sorry this is not detailed - the project includes mongodb node js etc .... If anyone feels they may be able to help, will give more details and code that may be needed

*inspect = Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mediataplatform.com/COU_TEST.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2-54-159-65-110.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/storeDetails'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

```
strVar += "          <form id=\"loginform\" name=\"loginform\" 
method=\"POST\" action=\"http:\/\/ec2-54-159-65-110.compute-
1.amazonaws.com:3000\/storeDetails\">";
strVar += "            <input type=\"hidden\" id = 'selectedEmotion' name = 
\"selectedEmotion\" value='99'>";

    ReferenceError: collection is not defined
    at /home/ubuntu/expressproject/routes/index.js:118:3
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
    (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next 
   (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch 
   (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
   (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at 
   /home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params 
   (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next 
   (/home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at /home/ubuntu/expressproject/node_modules/express-mongo-db/index.js:23:5
```

Comment: You will have to include more details and especially codes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you facing with 2 problems

1. Your NodeJS app: collection variable is not defined, you need to inspect this variable declaration.
2. Mix-content problem: To fix this, you need to use https in your API. Web browser need to block http request that make call from https because of security.

Comment: thanks for that - yes - i tried changing the call to https - seemed to be obvious - BUT the app would then just refuse the connection altogether ....